# single letter regex operations in R

Tags: regex, r, gsub

I'm trying to identify in Hebrew text incidents where i have a word (with 2 or more words) followed by single letter. I need to match these instances, and then concatenate the single letter to its' preceding word. Any text might have multiple incidents of that:
Example:

```
texts <- c("שלום חברי צה ל היקרים", "נכון לא נכון קשק ש בבטחון", "צה ל ינצח ")
```

I need to replace it to:

```
texts <- c("שלום חברי צהל היקרים", "נכון לא נכון קשקש בבטחון", "צהל ינצח ")
```

Thank you for the suggestions

Comment: Try `gsub("(*UCP)(*UTF)\\s+\\p{Hebrew}\\b","\\1",texts, perl=TRUE)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew i think you missed a capturing group

Comment: Yes, @rock321987, I knew I missed something. So, Dima, please check http://ideone.com/RWZfAF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [here](http://symbolcodes.tlt.psu.edu/bylanguage/hebrewchart.html), the hebrew letter unicode range is from `05D0-05F2`, so you can specify the unicode range in the character class which will then match a single hebrew letter. Specifying the space as the word boundary on each side, you can match a single letter word and substitute with the capture group to remove the space before the letter.

```
gsub("\\s([\u05D0-\u05F2]\\s)", "\\1", texts)  # hebrew letter unicode range
# [1] "שלום חברי צהל היקרים"     "נכון לא נכון קשקש בבטחון" "צהל ינצח "
```

Hebrew symbols unicode range from [here](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0590.pdf), you can adjust accordingly based on what you need.

```
gsub("\\s([\u0590-\u05FF]\\s)", "\\1", texts)  
# [1] "שלום חברי צהל היקרים"     "נכון לא נכון קשקש בבטחון" "צהל ינצח "
```